# python web scraping - URL not matching Chrome Inspect results

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to retrieve some data from the below links, but my requests lead to different results when I change the URL, by retrieving the URL after clicking on the next page button on the bottom of the website (https://www.carmax.com/cars?location=all).

## Code that works for the initial URL

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

car_url = "https://www.carmax.com/cars?location=all"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(car_url, headers = headers)
html_doc = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')

# Information that I am looking for
info = soup.find_all('div', class_='vehicle-browse--result--info')
```

When I run this same code using the next page of the website, there is no class of "class_='vehicle-browse--result--info'" in the response.

## Code with new URL from the next page

```
url_test = 'https://www.carmax.com/search?location=all#BT=0&Distance=all&ExposedCategories=249+250+1001+1000+265+999+772&ExposedDimensions=249+250+1001+1000+265+999+772&Page=4&PerPage=20&SortKey=0&StartIndex=80&Zip=20877'
test_request = requests.get(url_test, headers = headers)
html_doc_test = test_request.text
soup_test = BeautifulSoup(html_doc_test, 'lxml')

# This returns a blank object, not providing me the info I need
info_test = soup_test.find_all('div', class_='vehicle-browse--result--info')
```

The new URL (which is one of the next pages when you click the next arrow on the initial URL) does not have the same results.  What can I do to receive the same response for the next page?

For additional detail, when I click "Inspect" when using Google Chrome on the website, I do see the same type of information as the initial URL, but for some reason that does not translate to the code.

Comment: Maybe the response differs depending on the client browser type in the request header? Can you check that? Or a cookie is placed in your browser upon the initial site load?

Comment: How should I check that? @MartinSeehafer

Comment: i've checked and both of them contain `'div', class_='vehicle-browse--result--info'`

Comment: I checked and there is a cookie placed in your browser. Maybe you have to deliver that back.

Comment: @MartinSeehafer thanks, how do you deliver a cookie back?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the page is dynamically generated. [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and a driver like [Chrome](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) can load the injected DOM and grab the HTML on the fly:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome = webdriver.Chrome()
chrome.get("https://www.carmax.com/search?location=all#BT=0&Distance=all&ExposedCategories=249+250+1001+1000+265+999+772&ExposedDimensions=249+250+1001+1000+265+999+772&Page=4&PerPage=20&SortKey=0&StartIndex=80&Zip=20877")

for elem in chrome.find_elements_by_class_name("vehicle-browse--result--info"):
    print(elem.text) # or just use elem
```

Output:

```
No-haggle price$22,998*Mileage12K6 Reviews
GET PRE-QUALIFIED
CarMax Gaithersburg
Gaithersburg, MD
Stock #:16201078

No-haggle price$13,998*Mileage52K46 Reviews
GET PRE-QUALIFIED
CarMax Gaithersburg
Gaithersburg, MD
Stock #:15916654

No-haggle price$40,998*Mileage28K16 Reviews
GET PRE-QUALIFIED
CarMax Gaithersburg
Gaithersburg, MD
Stock #:16227545

No-haggle price$19,998*Mileage7K0 Reviews
GET PRE-QUALIFIED
CarMax Gaithersburg
Gaithersburg, MD
Stock #:16187367

No-haggle price$18,998*Mileage12K95 Reviews
GET PRE-QUALIFIED
CarMax Gaithersburg
Gaithersburg, MD
Stock #:16227745

No-haggle price$49,998*Mileage10K2 Reviews
GET PRE-QUALIFIED
CarMax Gaithersburg
Gaithersburg, MD
Stock #:16227961

No-haggle price$23,598*Mileage34K1 Review
GET PRE-QUALIFIED
CarMax Gaithersburg
Gaithersburg, MD
Stock #:16269716

No-haggle price$24,998*Mileage38K1 Review
GET PRE-QUALIFIED
CarMax Gaithersburg
Gaithersburg, MD
Stock #:16227325

No-haggle price$17,998*Mileage5K36 Reviews
GET PRE-QUALIFIED
CarMax Gaithersburg
Gaithersburg, MD
Stock #:16032863

No-haggle price$15,998*Mileage12K36 Reviews
GET PRE-QUALIFIED
CarMax Gaithersburg
Gaithersburg, MD
Stock #:16033129

No-haggle price$14,598*Mileage56K126 Reviews
GET PRE-QUALIFIED
CarMax Gaithersburg
Gaithersburg, MD
Stock #:15974221

No-haggle price$18,998*Mileage14K2 Reviews
GET PRE-QUALIFIED
CarMax Gaithersburg
Gaithersburg, MD
Stock #:16227491

No-haggle price$16,998*Mileage20K36 Reviews
GET PRE-QUALIFIED
CarMax Gaithersburg
Gaithersburg, MD
Stock #:16227699

No-haggle price$18,598*Mileage24K36 Reviews
GET PRE-QUALIFIED
CarMax Gaithersburg
Gaithersburg, MD
Stock #:16269723

No-haggle price$14,998*Mileage35K151 Reviews
GET PRE-QUALIFIED
CarMax Gaithersburg
Gaithersburg, MD
Stock #:16291864

No-haggle price$15,598*Mileage54K151 Reviews
GET PRE-QUALIFIED
CarMax Gaithersburg
Gaithersburg, MD
Stock #:16318227

No-haggle price$14,998*Mileage45K36 Reviews
GET PRE-QUALIFIED
CarMax Gaithersburg
Gaithersburg, MD
Stock #:16402895

No-haggle price$17,998*Mileage12K36 Reviews
GET PRE-QUALIFIED
CarMax Gaithersburg
Gaithersburg, MD
Stock #:16416608

No-haggle price$18,998*Mileage24K151 Reviews
GET PRE-QUALIFIED
CarMax Gaithersburg
Gaithersburg, MD
Stock #:16246905

No-haggle price$30,998*Mileage33K31 Reviews
GET PRE-QUALIFIED
CarMax Gaithersburg
Gaithersburg, MD
Stock #:16187751
```

Answer (score 0):

Next page content generated by JS, you can use selenium instead of requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

car_url = "https://www.carmax.com/search?location=all#BT=0&Distance=all&ExposedCategories=249+250+1001+1000+265+999+772&ExposedDimensions=249+250+1001+1000+265+999+772&Page=4&PerPage=20&SortKey=0&StartIndex=80&Zip=20877"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()#copy chromedriver in your python directory
driver.get(car_url)
html_doc = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
print soup.find_all('div', class_='vehicle-browse--result--info')
driver.close()
```